# Change ACL permission to 2500 folders with powershell

Tags: powershell, acl

I need to change security advanced permissions to 2500 folders, but I'm not so skilled to write a script that meet my requirements... I searched but I've found only scripts for a single folder and not spedcial permission.

I've 3 security groups inherited (for example 'zona parma'), some folders must have only zona parma, others only group2 or group3.

I've 3 CSV files with folder's names for each group that can be used as source.

I need to disable hineritance and convert inherited permissions into explicit permissions on this object.
I need that security groups, have special permission like image
[Advanced permission image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zR21F.png)

I've modified a folder that meet my requirements with command
Get-Acl "E:\Share\Dati\COMUNE\AreaPaghe\001A0093 - ABN SRL" | fl *
I've obtained this:
[folder properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKWrw.png)

Any help is very appreciated.....

Comment: Can't you use inheritence?  Icacls might be easier than powershell.

Comment: I'd recommend reading about the [NTFSSecurity](https://ntfssecurity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module. It makes tasks like this easier. Get-Acl and Set-Acl require too much messing about.

Comment: Many thanks both solutions are ok but I need to change security to 2500 folder how can I automate this process?

Comment: You can automate using `icacls` or the `NTFSSecurity` module, but no one here is going to write your automation script for you. That isn't [how the site works](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to all

I've resolved by using a batch procedure that copy security acl from a folder to another with

get-acl \fs1\shared\accounting | Set-Acl \fs1\shared\sales